# How to enable CORS between http://localhost:3000/ and TMDB api in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, cors

I'm facing error where I can't get the data from TMDB API.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

axios.js setup

```
import axios from "axios";  
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
})  
export default instance;
```

request.js setup:

```
const API_KEY = "xxx";  
const request = {  
  fetchTrending: `/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`,  
  fetchNetflixOriginal: `/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_networks=213`,  
}  
export default request;
```

App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
        //if [], run once when row load, and dont run again
        console.log("rrrrsd >>> ", typeof(fetchUrl))

        async function fetchData(){
            const response = await axios.get(fetchUrl, {
                headers:{
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                }
            }).then(function (response){
                console.log('response >>>>', response.data)
            }).catch(function (error){
                if(error.response){
                    console.log('response error >>>', error.response.headers)
                }
                else if(error.request){
                    console.log('error request >>>', error.request)
                }
                else{
                    console.log('message error >>>', error.message)
                }
            })

        }
        fetchData()
    },[fetchUrl])
```

Please help me to enable CORS between TMDB API and ReactJS localHost

Answer (score 0):

use a google chrome extension like (CORS Domain) or (Allow CORS )
I face the same problem yesterday and the extension fix it

Comment: For me it still gives out  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' error. For testing purpose i change the fetchUrl to "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day?api_key=xxx", and it gives the data. I suspect the fetchUrl is not correct.

Comment: @rafalias did you try the extensions?

Comment: yes i did turn on the Allow Cors at the localHost:3000